# Galleria and Picasa/Flickr: Sorting pictures to show newest uploaded

Tags: galleria

I am new to javascript and web design in general.  I am having issues with sorting my picasa pictures so that they are shown with the newest photos first.  This is my current code:

```
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
$('#galleria').galleria({
            picasa: 'useralbum:galleriajs/Demo',
            picasaOptions: {
                sort: 'date-posted-desc',
                imageSize: 800,
                thumbSize: 280
            },
            imageCrop: false,
            fullscreenCrop: false,
            thumbCrop: false,
            width: 377,
            height: 300,
            autoplay: true,
            imageTimeout: 60000,

});
```

No matter what I put for the sort: value, it comes up in the same order (what seems like oldest first).

I have been looking all over online for a solution but I have not been able to find one.  Any suggestions or sample code is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look into the Picasa API docs, where the actual call is made, it doesn’t seem to be a sort parameter:

http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/reference.html#Parameters

So, they either changed their API or the sort option has never been available. I’m sure you can sort them using JavaScript though, or sort them at Picasa.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My issue is that I do not know how to sort them through JavaScript.  I tried initiating galleria manually and using "datasource:data.sort(compare)" but I do not think I am using it right as the data that is being pulled does not act like an array.